# What do you call any person who is in a relationship?

Tags: single-word-requests

In speaking directly to a person of any gender, what might the identifier be for them in terms of their relationship?

For example, "wife" would describe a person who is the female in a married relationship (generally); but is there a good word to use to describe the same, but for any relationship and either partner, other than "person in a relationship"?

Comment: Please provide more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjective **Attached**

> married, engaged, or associated in an exclusive sexual relationship ⇒
>   "it's no good dancing with her, she's already attached" ([Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/attached))

(I would prefer to use "romantic" rather than "sexual" in the definition.)

I don't hear this one too often anymore, but, from what I remember, it was fairly common forty years ago. Now we would just say either "married" or "seeing someone".

Comment: Since you and I share a name, I'll add my comment to your answer:  *spoken for* is also used for this.

Comment: Why do you divide all relationships into these two kinds,"married" and "seeing someone"? What about who is not married and is not seeing someone? It is interesting for me as a cultural aspect.

Comment: You're right. I should have said "all romantic relationships".

Comment: This one word sums it up the best I've found, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

"She's in a ***"committed"*** relationship is generally understood without disclosing the gender of the partner or the type of relationship or living arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

[A very similar question has come up before.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76006/is-there-a-more-concise-term-for-a-long-term-girlfriend-boyfriend-than-signific)

I suggested ***partner,*** which satifies the requirements of not specifying a person’s sex or the nature of the relationship — except that it is a committed partnership of some kind.

Comment: How can you recognize which kind of partnership it is? Because It is used in business too or am I wrong?

Comment: Context, context, context. But yes, there can be an ambiguity when one's business partner is of the opposite sex (or even the same sex). However that's usually solved by using the term *business partner*. And then there's *life partner* or *significant other* or any of the terms at the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

The usual gender-neutral terms to use are

- *Spouse*, for a married couple
- *Partner*, for an intimately committed couple

Answer (score 0):

If the person is into Mathematics you could call them a *tuple-roomie*.