# Relationship Questions

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

What is it called when you're living with your boyfriend/girlfriend but you are not married yet?

What is it called when a couple decides they don't want to get married but plays the role of a married couple?

Comment: cohabitation is living together before marriage, the formal term. Informally, we say: living together. The second question is: pretending to be married but I don't think there's an app (whoops), word for that. [joke]

Comment: I would say it is nobody's business, except the IRS's when you file your returns.

Comment: In Norway the individual is the other person's "samboer", meaning roughly "person living at the same address".

Comment: And, of course, the US informal/slightly pejorative term is "shacking up".

Comment: In the early 1980s, when cohabitation was still slightly frowned upon, I remember asking a young woman I was interviewing (and I find it unbelievable, given today's social climate, that I would have asked her in quite that way) whether she was married. Without hesitation, or shyness, she shot back at me *No I'm living in sin as a matter of fact*. And it was my face which was red, not hers.

Comment: The answers to this question might be relevant, although it focuses more on the length and seriousness of the relationship than on the physical arrangements: [Is there a more concise term for a long-term girlfriend/boyfriend than “significant other”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76006/is-there-a-more-concise-term-for-a-long-term-girlfriend-boyfriend-than-signific)

Comment: My recently-married neighbors used to call themselves "sposes" as in "were sposed to be spouses by now." I can find no indication of anybody else using this, so offer it to you.

Comment: @DougGlancy - I think I heard that once.

Comment: There are a few jurisdictions in the US where if you hold yourself out to be married under these circumstances, then you are.

Comment: @deadrat - There used to be "common law marriage" in many states, where cohabiting for some period of years would result in the couple being considered legally married.  I'm not sure if that's true anywhere anymore, though.

Comment: @HotLicks Five states and DC currently, with varying restrictions; two more states, grandfathered.  And all states recognize common-law marriages from those jurisdictions.  Cohabitation is necessary but not sufficient.  Couples must represent themselves as a married couple.

Answer (score 7):

You would say such couples were ***cohabiting***.

> **cohabit**: *intransitive verb* To live together as or as if a married couple - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cohabit)
>
> *They cohabited in a small apartment in the city.*

Comment: Should `cohabiting` be `cohabitating`?

Comment: No, the word is cohabiting. This is another example of people inventing new words when we already had one that fit, like "orientate" when we already had orient, and "administrate" when we already had administer.

Comment: And don't even start me on conversating.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends upon the perceived state of your relationship and how much you want to reveal.

A simple "Boyfriend/girlfriend" (sometimes even just "friend") is acceptable even for a couple living together.

In some places, the law gives rights to couples who live together more than a certain amount of time, also called *[common-law marriage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-law_marriage)* or a *de facto relationship*. Members of such couples refer to each other as "common-law husband/wife" or even just "husband/wife", even if they're not actually  married.

And finally, people who have gone through the engagement ritual will call each other *[fiancé/fiancée](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engagement)* even if "setting a date" for the wedding is a far-off proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Among my circle of friends in California, we (somewhat tongue-in-cheek) call it an **MLR** (marriage-like relationship) when two people are essentially living a married lifestyle but have not taken formal marriage vows. This is a term we (as far as I know) made up and that is not used anywhere else, but if you like it, feel free to spread it around.

Answer (score 1):

*Shacking up* is an informal way of saying *cohabiting*. On a form you might fill in *cohabiting*. Talking with friends or family you might say "*shacking up*".

> *Shack up*: Verb: shack up
>
> Share living quarters; usually said of people who are not married and live together as a couple
>   - cohabit, live together
>
> Derived forms: shacking up, shacked up, shacks up
>
> Type of: dwell, inhabit, live, populate
>
> -- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=shack+up)